# forcing a process into swap and restoring it into memory

Tags: debian, swap

I'm doing some tests in Debian Linux on an arm sbc. There seem to be some issues which I couldn't confirm if it may be related to my zram swap setup.

Is there a way when I run a particular program to suspend it (e.g. control-z) 
and what I want to do is:

1. to have Linux page out that process memory image into swap
2. and I'd later restore it e.g. do a `fg` and have Linux retrieve it from swap and have it running again?

Is there a way to do (1) and (2) while there are still rather plenty of free unused memory? I simply want the relevant process to be swapped out for the purpose of the tests and issue isolation.
In addition, how do I monitor that to see if it is paged out to swap and restored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if the Linux kernel offers such a facility in the user space. What you are trying to do here is to take over the function of the Linux kernel. This may not go well with the people who are engaged with designing the security aspects of the Linux kernel.